# Cannot Publish/Deploy Django/Python site in local IIS (through Visual Studio publish)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, iis

I had trouble deploying to local IIS my DjangoWebProject from Visual Studio (2019).

```
1) This is for Windows 10 environment.
2) Used stack: Python/Django/MongoDB/Javascript/D3
3) IIS works and successfully shows the default IIS site (tried from localhost and another machine)
4) Everything works great! I could successfully code/build the site and tested everything is working in debug mode (from VS) - e.g. it opens up http://localhost:<portnumber> in Chrome/EDge and the whole website works perfectly with all the form submission etc. etc.
3) Now I wanted to create the internal site published so other users can access and I tried Publish option...

WebpublishMethod: MSDeploy
Server Name: <my machine name>
Site name: Default Web Site
Destination URL: <my machine name>.corp.<my company>.com
Validate Connection : Successful
```

Other conf details:

```
ExcludeAppData: False
SkipExtraFileOnServer: True
MSDeployPublishMethod: InProc
EnableMSDeploybackup: True
```

It gets published and it creates all the folder structure and everything (including resource files etc. needed) in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app location and the folder structure is consistent with the Visual Studio folder structure for code - it shows all the files like

```
__init__.py
forms.py
models.py
tests.py
views.py
```

etc.

plus all the required javascript and d3 code and everything.

BUT THE PROBLEM:
When I go to the site http://my-server-name.corp.my-company.com it does not show the site...

If I navigate to the proper location and specifically load the index.html - it does not run the python or django engine and so it shows like this in browser...

```
Chrome Browser: http://<my server name>.corp.<my company>.com
------------------------------------------------------
{% extends "app/layout.html" %} {% block content %}

Please enter the date range
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.fromDate.label_tag}} {{form.fromDate}}   {{form.toDate.label_tag}}   {{form.toDate}} {{form.guid}}   {{form.topcat}} 
{% if ratingResult %}
BarGraph Showing Rating Count Distribution
Table Showing Rating Count Distribution
{% for cat in ratingResult %} {% endfor %}
Rating  Count
Rating {{cat.overall_rating}}   {{cat.count}}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Obviously the deployment did not work properly - it just copied the files. How to do a proper deployment for Django/Python through VS?

Thanks in advance for all the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You will have to run a WSGI server and proxy it to get Django working.

Comment: you need to enable cgi feature of iis using control panel and configure Django with iis. [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019) may help you to configure Django in iis.

Comment: Well I followed the link and it did not work. I will post the detailed error soon.

Comment: But thanks a lot - I found the link and it is helpful. Just that I am probably missing something or doing something wrong. Could not figure out yet.